# finding the right direction while moving your finger in android devices

Tags: android, motion-detection, motionevent

I'm currently processing movement on Android and I used   `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`.

I calculate `currentx =(int) event.getX()/size` and `currenty=event.gety()/size`, which gives me the integer base on the size of grid which I work on. Howevor, I want a way to find where the current `y` is changed while moving and decide to do something after that.

For example, if the size is equal to `10` then in `x=150` and `y=150` my `currentx` would be `15` and and `currenty` would be `15` but when `currenty` changed to something like `16` that means `150<event.get(y)<160`. I want to know I'm in down direction etcetera.

Comment: Please provide us with a working sample of your code. As of now, your question is too vague to be answered

Comment: i copy a sample code here because the description above wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
//mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

int action = event.getActionMasked();

switch (action) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialX = event.getX();
        initialY = event.getY();

        Log.d(TAG, "Action was DOWN");
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        Log.d(TAG, "Action was MOVE");
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        float finalX = event.getX();
        float finalY = event.getY();

        Log.d(TAG, "Action was UP");

        if (initialX < finalX) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Left to Right swipe performed");
        }

        if (initialX > finalX) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Right to Left swipe performed");
        }

        if (initialY < finalY) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Up to Down swipe performed");
        }

        if (initialY > finalY) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Down to Up swipe performed");
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        Log.d(TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
        Log.d(TAG, "Movement occurred outside bounds of current screen element");
        break;
}

return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
```

---

here is my code

```
private int getDirection(float startx, float starty,float endx ,float endy )
{

int direction=-1;

    startx = (((int) startx / _size) *_size) ;
    starty = (((int) starty / _size) * _size) ;
    endx = (((int) endx / _size) * _size) ;
    endy = (((int) endy / _size) * _size) ;


  //  Log.i("direction","startx:"+startx+"endx:"+endx+"starty: "+starty+"endy: "+endy+" ");


    if (starty==endy)
    {
        direction= 0;

        return direction;

    }
    if(startx==endx)
    {
        direction =1;
       return direction;
    }

    if(Math.abs(startx-endx)==Math.abs(starty-endy))
    {

        direction =2;
       return direction;



    }



    else 
    {
        direction =-1;
    return direction;
    }





}
```

---

so i can find i'm in horizantal or vertical or non of these 2 cordinates but i need a way to compare the previous and current orientation while in action.move some thing like onDirectionChanggeListener
i can use action_up but i need it during move action.